# Links to my WP Blog suddenly will not show images on my Facebook. No changes in code, what is the issue?

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress

Title explains the issue I am having. When I post a link to a WP blog post onto Facebook, none of the images are getting inserted by Facebook. I haven't touched any of the code, nor have I used any new plugins. It worked for years, and now it just doesn't. Does anyone know what the problem may be?

Answer (score 1):

This problem happens from time to time, and it is normally a temporary problem. I've seen it lots of times with different links/sites. It is probably related to some error (at Facebooks end) when Facebook loaded your URL. Wait about 1 day for Facebook's caches to be flushed and the problem will hopefully be solved.

Comment: Hey Alfred thanks for the advice, unfortunately this has been going on for over 3 weeks.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Facebook's Linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to check out how Facebook 'sees' your website.
This will also flush their cache.

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for telling me about this feature. I tried putting the URL of the site (followthebottle.com) but it comes up with this error ---> Error Parsing URL: Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped. <-- Any idea what that might mean?

Comment: does your website allow bots to scrape your website? Facebook also might have set a timeout for requests to URLs. Your website takes about 6-10 seconds to load, this is long.

Comment: I am not sure, I didn't build the site I only maintain it. I would have to look into the source files to see if it can be scraped right?